# Salesforce - one WSDL for Sandbox and Production?

Tags: salesforce

So, I'm creating a salesforce app the currently hits a sandbox account just fine.

Our production and sandbox accounts are exactly the same in terms of fields.

Now, when I created my web reference in visual studio, a URL was added to the config file for test.salesforce.com , this url is also in the WSDL.

Can I change the URL in the config for production and have everything be okay? I have read conflicting idea on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're keeping the 2 environments in sync, then you'll notice that the only different in the WSDLs is the service URL. So, yes, its safe to change this in the properties, or to override it at runtime (via the .Url property) to switch between the 2.