# Change salesforce wsdl endpoint to production

Tags: c#, wsdl, salesforce, endpoint

I have been doing some work on a salesforce.com integration and it is all fine in test, which we have been testing the different salesforce systems on by changing our API login credentials.  Now it's time to go live, I have found that the service endpoint, which is stored in the WSDL, has to be updated.  The only way I can see to change this is to completely replace the 'dev/test' wsdl with the 'live' wsdl, re-build and re-deploy.

There must be an easier way to swap between dev/test and live wsdl or endpoints for salesforce.  How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: This might be of assistance: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10214366/361599

Answer (score 0):

You can use the config file to override the Salesforce web service URL that was extracted from the WSDL.

Failing that, look for the URL property on the generated web reference class. I think you can also define it in the constructor.

If you are using the Enterprise WSDL and there are differences in the schema between the two orgs you will need to update the definition.

Comment: I think I'll need to retain both references, but what's the best way to swap between them in code? I have a private member of type SforceService which I use for my operations, but now that needs to be of a different type depending on the environment it's running against.  The most elegant way would be using #if !DEBUG preprocessor directives to change a namespace alias, but I need to run release code on UAT so can't use that method.

Comment: @Craig Have you imported two difference Enterprise WSDLs into the same project?

Comment: Yes.  I basically have a sforce (live) reference and a sforce.sandbox (dev/test) reference, and want to find the best way to switch between both without having to code everything twice.

Comment: Rather than using the DEBUG conditional compilation symbol, define your own symbols and setup different build configurations to switch between them. [Frankenstein's monster build configurations](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/06/frankensteins-monster-build.html)

Comment: I'd rather have something I could inspect, e.g., web.config setting, and not have to rely on the correct build configuration having being used.

Comment: You might be better off with the Partner API. It will handle both orgs and the schema differences from the one WSDL. You will need to code for the differences, but it isn't too difficult.

Comment: You can't just swap out the urls, with salesforce it wants you to login first which returns an object containing a session id and the url endpoint

Comment: @TheMuffinMan if one org is a sandbox and the other is production you still need to toggle the URL between test.salesforce.com and login.salesforce.com. Then switch over to the url endpoint from the login call.